# How to Handle Different Timezone in Kafka Streams?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

So I was evaluating the Kafka Streams and what it can do to see if it can fit my use case as I needed to do the aggregation of sensor's data for each 15min, Hourly, Daily and found it useful due to its Windowing feature.
As I can create windows by applying `windowedBy()` on `KGroupedStream` but the problem is that windows are created in UTC and i want my data to be grouped by its originating timezone not by UTC Timezone as it hampers the aggregation so can any one help me on this.

Comment: The times are grouped by unix epoch time, so whatever anaysis you need to do, why can't you shift those times?

Comment: You'll need to think through the nature of time zones in a lot more detail.  For example, in the US Pacific time zone, it is offset -8 hours from UTC during standard time, and -7 hours from UTC during daylight saving time.  Thus, the "day" is 25 hours long on the spring transition day, and 23 hours long on the fall transition day.  If you need to keep separate groupings for every time zone in the world, your data will certainly balloon to very large proportions.  Then again, perhaps such detail is not important to you? Think it through.

Comment: @cricket_007 because i have to save those result back and show them to user in there respective timezone

Comment: You should preserve the unix epoch times, then let the users convert to their own `LocalDateTime` (assuming Java 8 API)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can "shift" the timestamps using a custom `TimestampExtractor` -- before you write the result back into the output topic, you can use a `Transformer` and "shift" the timestamps back via `context.forward(key, value, To.all().withTimestamps())`.

Feature request ticket: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/KAFKA-7911

Comment: Yes sir, I did that exactly though i didn't used `Transformer` and still i can see my output as expected so do i have to use The `Transformer`

Comment: Well. If you don't shift the data back, the timestamps will be in UTC timezone. If that is not a problem, you don't need to shift them back.

Answer (score 0):

So to solve this issue I created custom `TimestampExtractor` and used it to change the streams window creation time to record time from the payload as show below.

```
public class RecordTimeStampExtractor implements TimestampExtractor {

    @Override
    public long extract(ConsumerRecord<Object, Object> record, long previousTimestamp) {
        JsonObject data = (JsonObject) new JsonParser().parse(record.value().toString());
        Timestamp recordTimestamp = Timestamp.valueOf(data.get(Constant.SLOT).getAsString());
        return recordTimestamp.getTime();
    }

}
```

so now I have tested it with my local timezone since yesterday which is IST 05:30 and its working fine also kafka streams are creating windows based on records timestamp. Will test with other timezone as well and update the answer